# Pandas loc function just return NaN when assign the value in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi thanks for looking at my question! I am trying to change a column in my dataframe based on the condition of another column.

I have two dataframe, the first one called "df_Ckt" is used to find a year_value with certain circuit and certain year, it looks like this:

```
    df_Ckt.head(5)
    Circuit Key    2019   2020    2021    2022    2023    2024    2025    2026       2027     2028
    0   CKT_4340_00865  9.256492    9.320154    9.658590    9.674177    9.674177    9.674177    9.674177    9.674177    9.674177    9.674177
    1   CKT_14438_00891 1.078450    1.102765    1.227634    1.412518    1.723032    1.929562    2.140825    2.339290    2.555398    2.752190
    2   CKT_37_01894    6.214399    6.372979    6.549099    6.822940    7.258766    7.554228    7.865580    8.155443    8.469345    8.737263
    3   CKT_3543_03099  7.658913    7.759223    7.872652    7.889068    7.915327    7.930130    8.965180    8.981075    8.998183    9.013649
    4   CKT_4380_03370  8.616798    8.633209    8.830170    9.123515    9.581061    9.885816    10.192292   10.476004   9.872779    10.153234
```

Another dataframe called "df" look like below:

```
df.head(5)
circuit_key        year calculated
0   CKT_5670_00020  2019    NA
1   CKT_5670_00020  2019    NA
2   CKT_5670_00020  2019    NA
3   CKT_5670_00020  2019    NA
4   CKT_5670_00020  2019    NA
```

The year range in "df" is 2019-2028, I added a column called "calculated" to capture the year_value in the df_Ckt. It should look like this:

```
 circuit_key           year calculated
0   CKT_5670_00020  2019    8.241063
1   CKT_5670_00020  2019    8.241063
2   CKT_5670_00020  2019    8.241063
3   CKT_5670_00020  2019    8.241063
4   CKT_5670_00020  2019    8.241063
```

My code looks like this:

```
df["calculated"]="NA"
for year in range (2019,2029):
    year_value=df_Ckt.loc[df_Ckt['Circuit Key']=="circuit",year].reset_index(drop=True)
    df.loc[np.logical_and(df.year==year,df.calculated=="NA"),['calculated']]=year_value
    print(year,year_value)
```

The output is as below:

```
2019 0    8.241063
Name: 2019, dtype: float64
2020 0    8.252401
Name: 2020, dtype: float64
2021 0    8.309021
Name: 2021, dtype: float64
2022 0    8.403156
Name: 2022, dtype: float64
2023 0    8.55595
Name: 2023, dtype: float64
2024 0    8.656351
Name: 2024, dtype: float64
2025 0    8.759824
Name: 2025, dtype: float64
2026 0    8.856902
Name: 2026, dtype: float64
2027 0    8.940435
Name: 2027, dtype: float64
2028 0    9.008744
Name: 2028, dtype: float64
```

And when I want to test the column I modify, it is all NaN, seems like the loc function can not assign the value.

```
df['calculated']

        ... 
96440    NaN
96441    NaN
96442    NaN
Name: calculated, Length: 96443, dtype: object
```

Then I tried to assign constant variable to the column. I did some test as below:

```
df["calculated"]="NA"
for year in range (2019,2029):
    year_value=df_Ckt.loc[df_Ckt['Circuit Key']=="circuit",year].reset_index(drop=True)
    df.loc[np.logical_and(df.year==year,df.calculated=="NA"),['calculated']]=1
```

the output seems correct in this case:

```
0         1
1         1
2         1
         ..

Name: calculated1, Length: 96443, dtype: object
```

It seems that my "year_value" has some issues and it can't be assigned to a dataframe value. Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: Hi I added the dataset so it will be more clear about the dataframe.

Comment: Hi, `CKT_5670_00020` is not present in `df_Ckt`, can you edit either `df_Ckt` or the expected output in accordance to the input? Thanks(I dont think you need looping here)

Comment: I believe you may need either `df_Ckt.set_index('Circuit Key').stack().reset_index()` or `df_Ckt.melt('Circuit Key',var_name='year',value_name='calculated').sort_values('Circuit Key')` , post this if required you can `merge` with `df`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting `NaN` is because `year_value` is a series, not a single float value. To assign the calculated value, extract the calculated value from `year_value` series and that would solve it.

```
df["calculated"]="NA"
for year in range (2019,2029):
    year_value=df_Ckt.loc[df_Ckt['Circuit Key']=="circuit",year].reset_index(drop=True)
    df.loc[np.logical_and(df.year==year,df.calculated=="NA"),['calculated']]=year_value[0]
    print(year,year_value)
```